# How to localize a big text in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, localization

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 2 web site that needs localization. 
The recommended approach with ViewLocalizer and resources works well for simple strings, e.g. menu items, button labels, titles, etc. When it comes to more complex text (bold text, colored text, new lines, etc.) this way becomes bulky because I need to place some html code inside resources and use @Html.Raw (place html code inside resx just seems wrong and resx files don't have an html editor) or separate my text into smaller pieces (this way I end up with lots of localization keys like "TextItem1", "TextItem2")

Now, I want to localize my Privacy Policy and since it may contain paragraphs, lists, indentations, new lines, titles, subtitles, etc., I end up with a very ugly razor code like this (showing only one paragraph here):

```
    <div class="policy-paragraph">
        <div class="policy-title"><span>@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRTitle"]</span></div>
        <div class="policy-text">
            <span>
                @Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRLine1"]<br />
                @Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRLine2"]<br />
            </span>
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight1"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight2"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight3"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight4"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight5"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight5"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight6"]</span><br />
            <span class="text-indent bold">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRRight7"]</span><br /> 
            <span class="text-indent">@Localizer["Label_PolicyGDPRContactUs"]</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And now imagine that I want to split the text under "Label_PolicyGDPRRight4" into three lines or combine "Label_PolicyGDPRLine1" and "Label_PolicyGDPRLine2" into one or insert a bold text somewhere. Or combine my text in a different way depending on the localization

It seems easier to create separate partial views for each localization and don't use ViewLocalizer at all.

What are the best practices doing these kind of localizations in ASP.NET Core?

P.S.: a Privacy Policy is just an example, it may be any long text, a story, essay and so on.

Comment: you can use IHtmlLocalizer as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#view-localization)

Comment: Localization isn't meant for full content. You should employ a different strategy here. For example, you may store multiple "pages" in your CMS keyed to different cultures. Then, when querying out your content, you use the culture settings to query the right one. The built in localization is meant for UI, for the most part,